# When using SCIM to type Hangul, space moves the syllable before going to the next word

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, input

When I type Hangul using the SCIM input on Ubuntu, when I press space, the last syllable automatically moves over a space, then adds another space. This goes away if I press a period and backspace it, but it slows down my typing.

Example:
If I type 한굴, and then press space afterward, it looks like 한 글

Notice the space between the syllables.

Thanks.